# Install CGAL-4.11.1 locally without being root

Tags: software-installation, configuration, non-root-user

I am trying to install `CGAL-4.11.1` on a server locally without root privilege but so far I failed.

```
tar -xvzf cgal-releases-CGAL-4.11.1.tar.gz
cmake -DCGAL_DIR:/local_path .
make
make install
```

I get this error

```
-- Install configuration: "Release"
CMake Error at Installation/cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/share/doc/CGAL-4.11.1-I-900.
  Maybe need administrative privileges.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)



Makefile:61: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Above commands not working. Any suggestion how it should be done?

Comment: According to the `INSTALL` file, the installation directory is controlled by `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`

Comment: @steeldriver so the command line should be like `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/local_path .`, right?

Comment: ... for some suitable value of `/local_path` - if you want real help, you will need to be more specific than *"commands not working"*

Comment: @steeldriver I posted my error.

Comment: Yes, well `/usr/local` won't usually be writable without elevated privileges - I suggest you start over with an appropriate `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` of your choice